# Can you help me to do movable window in js

Tags: javascript, html, window

(sorry for my bad english)
Hello, I want to do movable window in js:
when you stay supported on the window, it moves, and when you release your mouse, the window stops to move.
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

To do this yourself, you need to bind the [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) event, [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) event, and [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) event to your movable object

`mousedown` = engage moving component state.

`mousemove` = when item is moving, shift the component's x,y coordinates by mouse motion offsets.

`mouseup` = disengage the moving component state

This isn't as easy as it sounds, and there are a lot of edge cases.  It might be easier to use an existing framework to help manage the complexity.

I found [interactjs.io](https://interactjs.io/) as an option.  I have no idea if it's any good, and have not used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp

Simple solution with comments to help explain whats going on (copy/paste from the link above):

```js
// Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- Draggable DIV -->
<div id="mydiv">
  <!-- Include a header DIV with the same name as the draggable DIV, followed by "header" -->
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>
```